# Echo 'file exists' error with bus device in kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to follow this example http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/code/sysfs_ex2.c which is basically a kernel module which will create a fake bus device with a busval attribute. According to the comments, I should be able to write to busval (which should fire up the store() function). However when i do

```
echo 2 > busval
```

I get the message `busval: File exists`. I tried

```
echo 2 >> busval
```

and I get `busval: Permission denied`. I get a similar error when i write a c program to open and write to the file. Using sudo doesn't fix the problem. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: try with sudo user. sudo echo 2> busval.

Comment: tried that and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @kernelator maybe the kernel module has not mentioned this module parameter to be accessed by user i.e. if you see module_param api

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` won't help you. You must fully switch user to root and do echo under root. I can't tell you for sure why `sudo` is not working with it, sorry.

You can also change bus attribute write permissions to `S_IWUGO`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to switch to root in my working environment (work rules). I do have sudo access but it is not working (even with S_IWUGO)

Comment: With S_IWUGO you don't have to access your file with sudo - it should work with regular user. If it's not then check your system settings - it might be SELinux or stuff like that. If your work rules doesn't allow you to be root then it might not allow you to access special files under /sys.